# How many concurrent users can run in JMeter in one machine

Tags: jmeter

This is for e-commerce project where the number of users login will be more. I have been given a benchmark 8000 concurrent users need to login and response time should be 3 minutes

Answer (score 0):

@abi , hi .

Let me provide couple notes here. 
Depending upon Your connection bandwidth ,  from my experience as performance test engineer, I'd say jmeter single instance usually holds up to 1k(1000)- 2k(2000) in best case users  load.

Considering You have a requirement for 8k (8000 users) load, You need to launch jmeter in distributed mode ( master <-> slaves).
For this config setup I'd recommend to go with 1 master node  and 4slaves. For that - You will need 5 machines (aws/azure, whatever) in the same sub-network.

Re more technical details on distributed setup, please take a look:

- in public [jmeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- please also look into this step-by-step [setup manual](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- Also, when i've been doing set-up  for 10k load for one of my recent projects - I did [couple notes for myself in g-doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1z4ZHBJEvR1CZplv0NkWkHEOAuqX9PYZiLAjsUXyNEEI/edit?usp=sharing)  .  Let me know if it opens fine for You.

Last note, If  You need to do some load/performance tests on APIs that require AUTHZ, I'd recommend to split authorize (IDP bypass) and performance scenario itself - in different thread groups. As usually IDP in DEVs/Stagings  does not hold much load . 
So at first You need to authorize w/o any load (1st Thread group). 
And in 2nd Thread group - start calling target APIs under the test.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on:

1. Your machine specifications (CPU, RAM, NIC card, hard drive, etc.)
2. The nature of your Test Plan (number of requests, size of requests/responses, number of [pre](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors)/[post processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), [assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions), [timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#timers), etc.)
3. Response time of your application

So if your test is a simple GET request which returns small text response - you might simulate 10 000 of users on a mid-range modern laptop. And if your test is connected with heavy requests, large responses, file uploads, etc. - it might be 1000 users.

---

1. Make sure to follow recommendations from [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. Make sure to have monitoring of resources usage of your system (CPU, RAM, Swap, etc.). You can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for this.
3. Make sure that your test [behaves like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)
4. Start with 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load until you reach 8000 virtual users or JMeter starts lacking resources, whatever comes the first. If you can simulate 8000 users from a single machine - you're good to go. If not - you will have to consider [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).